# perl line to remove lines with a value less than x

Tags: bash, perl

I have csv file that has numeric value in column 3. I dont want any lines where this value is less than `604800`. The following perl line is in my bash script that creates and edits this file. This line works OK but leaves about 20 lines with a 0 value in column 3 and I'm not sure why. It removes all other lines like supposed to. Could someone tell me why its missing these lines or provide a better solution.

```
perl -ne 'print if grep {$_>604800} /(\d{6,})/' ./temp/mergedreport.csv > ./temp/mergedreport1.csv
```

Comment: why don't you create a small file with those 20 lines in it, and see what happens?

Comment: Without knowing your data, the answer may be that that matching expression will match *anywhere* in the line, not just column 3. Do those 0-value lines have a string of digits >604800 somewhere else perhaps?

Comment: Does your CSV have any multi-line fields or quoted commas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have helped enormously if you could show your data, particularly the unwanted lines that are being printed

The problem is likely to be that your zeroes are just a single digit 0, whereas your regex is looking for the first six-digit number that it can find in the line. If it finds something *after* the third column that is greater than 604800 then the line will be printed

If your CSV is indeed *comma separated*, then you can check the third column explicitly by writing

```
perl -lne 'print if (split /,/)[2] >= 604_800' ./temp/mergedreport.csv
```

If it is tab-separated then that should be `(split /\t/)[2]`, and if it is just generally whitespace-separated then `(split)[2]`

Comment: you are correct. It was leaving single digit 0s. Your solution worked perfectly... Thanks much...

Answer (score 3):

You probably want:

```
perl -ne 'print if /(\d{6,})/ and $1 > 604_800'
```

You can also take advantage of Perl's autosplit mode (`-a`), which separates the lines into columns for you:

```
perl -ane 'print if $F[2] > 604_800'
```

The above assumes your columns are separated by whitespace; you can specify an alternative delimiter with the `-F` option. However, if it's a true CSV file, you should probably be using something like [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-CSV/) or [Parse::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Parse-CSV/).

A `grep` is superfluous here because your statements are running inside a `while (<>) { .. }` loop (thanks to the `-n`) so you only have to worry about one line at a time. (Unless you're trying to handle multiple numbers on a single line, in which case you should definitely be using `-F` or one of the CSV modules from CPAN.)

Answer (score 0):

awk to the rescue!

```
awk '$3>604800' file
```

if the separator comma, you need to add `-F,` option

Comment: `awk` to the rescue! SO improves if you upvote the answers you find useful and downvote the ones that are wrong.